# Macports Apache2 "Could not bind to address"

Tags: apache-http-server, macports

I have apache2 installed on Mac OS X 10.7.4 via [macports](http://www.macports.org/)

Recently I have not been able to access my localhost directory I get a 404, but I can access 127.0.0.1

I've tried restarting apache:

```
sudo /opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl stop
sudo /opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start
```

and I get the following errors:

```
(48)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(48)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
```

I've checked that web sharing is off. It seems like apache is already using these points or the service is not stopping correctly.

How can I find out what is using the ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "lsof" shell command can tell you exactly which process is using which files and socket addresses in the system. Just try a

```
sudo lsof
```

or, since the output will be a lot, better

```
sudo lsof | less
```

and look for something on the http ports. As usual

```
man lsof
```

will give you more information on how to customise the output.

Comment: Thanks `lsof -i :80` shows processes using that port. Any idea how to fix the Apache errors?

Comment: Well, the only way to let Apache bind to those ports is by getting rid of the processes that are using them, try the 'kill' shell command...

Comment: It seems that the mac version of apache has started `/usr/sbin/httpd` even though I have "web sharing" turned off. If I kill this process it restarts, even though it's disabled in the launch daemons. This seems to be what is stopping the macports apache running.

Answer (score 3):

For reference, in Mountain Lion 10.8.2, simply stopping the apache2 service did the trick:

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

That way the httpd processes won't restart, and the Macports apache2 server will start fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

In my Mac with Mojave (10.14.1), suddenly Apache couldn't serve IPv4 anymore, then gave me ERROR 403.  I tried to kill all apache (`sudo killall httpd`)... checking the PID's with

```
sudo lsof | grep AMP | grep apache
```

even didn't work... just IPv6 was available... still ERROR 403

What works for me: disable macOS’s built-in Apache server.

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

after that:

```
sudo apachectl -k restart
```

be happy :)